# Json Api and Custom Posts Type

Tags: wordpress, api, android-studio, custom-post-type, json-api

I use json-api (http://jsonapi.org/) to get data from my WordPress site to my Android Studio app. To get get posts I use the `get_posts`request.

I have installed "Custom Post Type UI" (CPT UI), but I cant't find a method like `get_mycptuiname` to get my CPT UI  post.

Comment: please put some code or what have you done so far .

Comment: if the plugin `CPT UI` don't create the API endpoint, you certainly need to create the custom post type yourself with a plugin. If you need help for this or other WordPress developement questions, look on this site : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com